# executeQueryAsync not working properly in SharePoint App

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ecmascript-5

I have a function below to get terms from Managed Metadata Service. Everything works fine when I call function once. But if I call it more times. It gives fatal error "The collection has not been initialized ..." Actually I use Single Page Application and it runs only when I open site at the beginning. It is took all my day and I need to call that function maybe 5-6 times in a page. Anyone can help? What is wrong on my code?

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(spContext.hostWeb.appWebUrl);
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
var termStore = termStores.getByName("Yönetilen Meta Veri Hizmeti");
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termsetguid);
var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
context.load(terms);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
try {
    var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
    var termList = [];
    while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
        termList.push(currentTerm.get_name());
    }} 
    catch (e) {
        common.logger.logWarning("Warning", "" , true);
    }
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
common.logger.logError("", "Error", true);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs in the following cases:

- when client object has not been requested explicitly or implicitly (`terms` in your case)
- `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` is invoked in a loop. Since the
  specified function is **async** the behavior could be unpredictable

Try to make variables as **local** (e.g. enclose it using anonymous function)

```
(function(){

   var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
   var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
   var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
   var termStore = termStores.getByName(termStoreName);
   var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termsetGuid);
   var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
   context.load(terms);
   context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

})();
```

Comment: Still same case... In my project I need to use that function twice or more times in one page. That gives error to me